# What is the method of taking Samadhi (that leads to death) ? Who are eligible to take Samaadhi?

Tags: death, samadhi

Various people that were not saints have taken Samadhi like - Bhagwan Ram and all his brothers tooks JalSamadhi .

So, What is the procedure of taking Samadhi ? Who are eligible to take Samadhi ?

**Here I am asking the type of Samadhi where people die after releasing their Prana**.

Where can I learn how to take Samadhi i.e.to release the aatma from the body by self ?

Comment: Samadhi is meditation for extended period of time, in yoga sutra starting patanjali explains it very well

Comment: @Youwillnotknowme What about Samadhi where people die and release their Prana.

Comment: Do you mean like Jala-samadhi kind of stuff specifically and not the Patanjali's Samadhi?

Comment: @Vivikta I wanted to Know Samadhi which leads to death.